# Does Sencha Touch 2.2.1 works with IBM Rational Test Workbench 8.5

Tags: extjs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, rational-test-workbench

The version of Rational Test Workbench (RTW) that comes with the IBM Worklight Development Studio 6.2 (latest) does not support some of the Sencha features, so it fails to get imported.

However, this restriction is overlooked in the full Rational Test Workbench Studio and the app can be imported to the Workbench. But after creating the test, once we execute the test the icons are not still recognized.

The App is created with Worklight Studio 6.0.0.2 using Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Kindly advice if someone has tried this before. Thanks.

Here is what the log says

CRRTWM6013I from component Android-BuildChain: configuration: {cache.dir=C:\RMBP\WorkSpace_Kavin.metadata.plugins

An exception stack trace is not available.

NLS unused message: CRRTWM6020W_EXECUTION_WARNING.systemaction in: com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.internal.log.LogMSG

An exception stack trace is not available.

Answer (score 0):

RTW does not support Sencha Touch.
You could have partial object recognition as HTML5 is supported.